# Should I align multiple search boxes horizontally or vertically?

Tags: forms, gui-design, layout, search

Which UI/Ux is better?
horizontally placed search boxes or vertically placed? I am trying to understand which pattern is good in terms of UX/UI and reducing the user's effort

I am thinking in a way that the horizontally aligned search boxes(the upper image)need more effort of eye scanning and entering the details.

[image: The upper image contains the horizontally placed search boxes and the bottom image contains the vertically aligned search boxes]

Comment: It would be a good idea to add screenshots/images of what you are describing. It is quite hard to understand.

Comment: Also, can you give us some context? What are you working on? What is the problem you're trying to solve here, and what efforts have you made towards this so far?

Comment: Hello @Avni, and welcome to UX.SE. I managed to find the image you meant to include and tidied up the question a bit. There are some remaining questions [@MikeMark](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/134468/#comment213820_134468) and [@MikeM](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/134468/#comment213821_134468) have raised in their comments, so feel free to [edit] your question to include any additional details that may help us provide an answer. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the response, Mike! I hope now it is understandable?

Comment: Thanks a lot, @maxathousand for helping me out. I tried again to explain my question, I hope it is understandable now.

Answer (score 1):

Between the 2 options, I find the 2nd option easier to digest. But also consider the following other ways to approach this.

1. Do some benchmarking on how other airlines and travel apps approach this.
2. Design a few variations of the design and show it to end-users and ask them to pick one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Ameen Akbar! I am working on a college project so I don't have any end-users.                                                                                                                     so I just wanted to know which pattern is right in terms of UX and UI, also which pattern is easily scanable and reduces user's effort.

Comment: anyone who uses websites to book flights can be considered end-users